# Flying from Lyon to Kuala Lumpur, do I need to recheck-in at London Heathrow transit?

Tags: transit, lhr, british-airways, oneworld, malaysia-airlines

I plan to travel from Lyon (France) to Kuala Lumpur (Malaysia) with a transit stop at London Heathrow (UK).

The former flight is **from Lyon Saint-Exupery (LYS) to London Heathrow (LHR) with British Airways** (Flight Code : BA 365).

The latter, after 3 hours and 10 minutes of transit, is **from London Heathrow (LHR) to Kuala-Lumpur (KUL) with Malaysia Airlines** (Flight Code : MH 3).

---

**My question is simple :** Do I need to recheck-in and check (take it and register again) my bags at London Heathrow (LHR) or is it managed by the company or the airport so I don't have to worry about that ?

---

**What I know :**

- British Airways and Malaysia Airlines are members of the same alliance since Malaysia Airlines joined it in 2013 (OneWorld)
- I have to change from Terminal 3 to Terminal 4 at London Heathrow (LHR)
- There is no code share. Each flight has its own flight code (BA365 for British and MH3 for Malaysian).

---

Comment: Is the flight all on a single ticket?

Comment: I still don't know as I didn't book the flight yet. The problem is that I use jetcost.com and they don't make it very clear before you book. What I know is that there isn't a code share (each flight has its own code : BA for British and MH for Malaysia).

Comment: I wouldn't know. You can always ask during the baggage check-in. If so, remember that baggage reclaim is on the other end of security. You have to go through border control and baggage check anyway if transferring, so you wouldn't be much slower.

Comment: Even on two tickets, BA should be fine to through-check as MH are OneWorld, though it may take a while at checkin. Coming back you might have trouble though if it's two tickets, as IIRC Malaysian are less keen on interlining across two tickets

Comment: If you can purchase all flights in one single transaction, paying all at once without distinguishing between paying for one flight here and one flight there, then it is a single ticket.

Answer (score 2):

If you are buying all your flights together in one single transaction, then yes your baggage will be checkled through. You will not need to collect your luggage in Heathrow. You should recieve all your boarding passes at the check in desk in LYS but even if you do not, you can collect your Malaysian Airlines boarding pass once you get to Terminal 4. Simply follow the purple signs for flight connections when you get to Heathrow. A free bus will transport you to Terninal 4. You do not need to enter the UK nor pass through UK immigration.

However there will be a security check at Heahrow because the UK government only trusts British airports to apply security screening.

(Even if you are buying several tickets through several separate unconnected transactions, it is BA policy to through-check to oneworld partners including Malaysian Airlines, however it may take some time to arrange this.)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to recheck your bags if you book two separate tickets and that the flights are not code shared.

British Airways and Malaysian are [members of oneworld](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/partners-and-alliances/oneworld); thus you may be able to get a code-share flight from either of the operators. If this is the case, then you will not have to re-check your bags.

Bottom line - it depends on how you book your ticket.

---

The way you have described your itinerary, it sounds like you have two point-to-point tickets. The first is LYS-LHR on BA365, and the second LHR-KUL on MH003.

In this scenario, you will need to collect your bags and re-check in for your second flight. Your bags will be checked into LHR on your BA365.

It also means, that for the purposes of immigration - you need to be able to enter the UK (ie, this is not an airside transit).

Comment: BA and MH do not codeshare within Europe but BA still provides interlined feed to MH flights on prime BA flights (on a single ticket). I don't think your answer is correct so far as it appears to suggest  that it is not possible to buy a BA and an MH flights together on one ticket.